# Correct way to handle absolute URL's in Javascript/PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, url-rewriting

I have Javascript that's run alongside URL rewriting, so it loads content from the wrong place if I use relative URL's. I need this to work on both a test server and a live server.

What's the correct solution here? Should I be using a Javascript function that forms the absolute URL's?

Comment: grab the current url, trim it, add the a/b/c

Comment: @starvator: Trim it to what exactly? If the website is in a virtual  directory the root might be `http://www.domain.com/approot/` :)

Comment: Maybe you need to use a variable $isLive = false;  then check it with if($isLive) { define('base_url', 'url-live'); } else { define('base_url', 'url-test'); }

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie really? I have a site in a virtual directory and when I grabbed the url it included the aspx page.. Strange

Comment: @starvator: I meant *what would you trim from a url where the website root is not at `/`* e.g. `http://www.domain.com/approot/somepage.aspx`?

Comment: ow, i meant to trim it from `http://www.domain.com/approot/somepage.aspx` to `http://www.domain.com/approot/` so that you can add your new page to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just define in your common file (header.php):-

```
<script> var baseUrl = '<?php echo BASE_URL;?>';</script>
```

and include your all js to below this code and access this var for use.

Answer (score 1):

After including  tag, use following. But remember you wont be able to use the variable in External

```
<script> 
    var siteBaseURL = '<?php echo BASE_URL;?>';
</script>
```

Because , PHP will ECHO any server side value and will send it as HTML , So PHP will send BASE_URL and such HTML With JavaSCRIPT will be included in browser.

But in any external JS Files like  say

```
 <script src="example.js"/>  Here you wont be able to access the above variable.
```

Comment: Re your second comment: If the variable is declared in the global namespace, you will be able to access it from any script with `window.siteBaseURL`.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie , yes correct . i had to say if he defined it as scope specific, then problems will occur

Comment: I think it was just the way it was worded that confused me :)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I develop on test vs live I only use "/css/location/cssfile.css" (this applies to any file) that way I don't have to modify anything.

Then when my HTML loads, it will call from the right location. The above translates into:

```
http://localhost/location/to/www/root/css/location/cssfile.css
```

or

```
http://test.com/css/location/cssfile.css
```

This will work for 50 sites:

/css/location/file.name

Would work for:

```
http://localhost/location/to/www/root
http://localhost/location/to/www/testsite1
http://localhost/location/to/www/testsite2
http://localhost/location/to/www/testsite3
```

etc

Comment: And you don't have to. Like I said, using the "/where/my/file/is" instead of the FULL ABSOLUTE PATH. You can develop for each site without actually hard coding it!

Comment: It doesn't matter. If you use /where/you/want/to/go/file.name then it doesn't matter where your root is at all.

Comment: A *root relative* path (such as your example) would always map back to the domain root. That is under browser control. I don't see how you would ever get the `http://localhost/location/to/www/root/css/location/cssfile.css` result you mentioned. You would more likely get `http://localhost/css/location/cssfile.css`